# FolderBrowserDialog last Folder Name

Tags: string, split, c++-cli, folderbrowserdialog

I'm new to C++/CLI and have a Question about the FolderBrowserDialog function.

Using ->SelectedPath gives me "C:\Folder\Subfolder\Selected Folder"

How can I save JUST "Selected Folder" to a string?

```
FolderBrowserDialog^ DestinationFolderDialog;
    DestinationFolderDialog = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog;

    System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = DestinationFolderDialog->ShowDialog();
    if (result == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        String^ path = DestinationFolderDialog->SelectedPath;
        SetDestinationPath(path);
        lblDestinationPath->Text = path;

    }
```

The way I set my Destination Path

And now I want to work with it

```
String^ pathSource = GetSourcePath();
String^ pathDest = GetDestinationPath();
```

Im trying to generate Symlinks.
So im Selecting "Y:\Movies\Movie_a" as Source
And im Selecting "X:\" as Destination for my Symlink Folder

To Create it I need to add "Movie_a" to "X:\"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to extract the last dir name from `C:\Folder\Subfolder\Selected Folder` then you can:

- use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method to acquire the last part from the path
- call [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `Path.PathSeparator` and take the last array element

**Updated** in respect to *@LucasTrzesniewski* comment

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just use `Path::GetFileName`

Comment: i cant get i to work, i dont know, could you give me a short excample how to split <br> String^ path and save it to an array?

Comment: Yes, this method works on strings and can't tell the difference between a file and a folder

Comment: If i just use **String^ folder = Path::GetFileName(pathSource);** its not working, it says it needs to be a Class or Namespace. What do i need to add?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You are correct. I've just treated it as a regular text where actually using `Path` is a better solution.